Unresolved reference: it in kotlin
I am trying to build a simple notes app according to this tutorial video but I am not able to create deleteTodo function because of unresolved reference of it keyword.
I am using compose (version 1.5.1) and kotlin version 1.9.24. I have tried:
changing kotlin version to 1.9.20
changing compose version to 1.5.13
restarting Android Studio
browsing other tutorials (but they were using it keyword as well)
Can anyone help, please?
P.S. It may be a dump mistake because I am a beginner in kotlin.
Here is my code:
my code

What do you expect it to be?

Please see [ask], including the section on what to include code as text and not images

Possible solution:
private val todoList = mutableListOf<Todo>()

fun deleteTodo(id: Int) {
    todoList.removeAll {
        it.id == id
    }
}

-you need to use curly brackets to apply a predicate to the list, and pass that it (reference to the Todo object) matches the id you passed(that you want to delete), if the predicate is true, it will remove the Todo object from the list.

Your Kotlin Version is 1.9.24. I also face this issue when I update my Kotlin version. You can downgrade to it the you can try its work.
kotlin = "1.9.0"


This problem is not due to the Kotlin version. It's a simple syntax error in the OP's code. It can be fixed as suggested by the other answer.
